# Why does my if statement evalute my variable as empty?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to create a Bash script to create an AWS EC2 instance.

Goal: improve my Bash scripting skills

In order to improve my bash scripting skills, I wanted to practice creating if statements in my script.
As shown above, I created the if statement to check if the variable new_ami is empty then to echo "Did not find it" but if it is not empty, it will echo "Found AMI".

Here is my script

```
ami=$(aws ec2 describe-images --owners self amazon --filters "Name=name, Values=amzn2-*.0-x86_64-gp2" "Name=state, Values=available" --profile XXXXXX --output json | jq '.Images | sort_by(.CreationDate) | last(.[]).ImageId')

new_ami=$(echo "${ami}" | sed 's/"//g')

echo $new_ami

if test -z "$new_ami"
then
    echo "Found AMI"
else
    echo "Did not find it"
fi
```

When I run my script, this is the result, I got

```
ami-0ce1e3f77cd41957e
Did not find it
```

I have a problem:

1. The script echoes the variable new_ami which shows that he variable is not empty but the if statement fails to echo "Found AMI" instead it echoes "Did not find it" which means that the variable new_ami is empty.
   How can this happen?
   Why is my if statement behaving like this?
   how do I fix it?
   Thank you for all the help

Comment: `-z "$new_ami"` evaluates to `true` if the length of the variable is zero (ie, the variable is undefined or has no value); switch your `echo` commands between the `then/else` blocks and you should be good to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@davidonstack `if test -z "$new_ami"` returns false, as it check for if variable has length.

So when its -z returns true, then expression will be executed, if false else expression will be executed.

Check more information in `man test`

```
-z string     True if the length of string is zero.
-n string     True if the length of string is nonzero.
```

Try to use `-n` as below

```
ami=$(aws ec2 describe-images --owners self amazon --filters "Name=name, Values=amzn2-*.0-x86_64-gp2" "Name=state, Values=available" --profile XXXXXX --output json | jq '.Images | sort_by(.CreationDate) | last(.[]).ImageId')

new_ami=$(echo "${ami}" | sed 's/"//g')

echo $new_ami

if test -n "$new_ami"
then
    echo "Found AMI"
else
    echo "Did not find it"
fi
```